# Partial mock test in Durable Function Orchestrator Function

Tags: c#, automated-tests, moq, azure-durable-functions

I'm trying to test the behaviour of an Orchestrator function and want to try to only mock calls that depends on external sources. This is to test that the combination of steps aka. the behaviour of the Orchestrator function aqually works.

I'm not interested in seperated tests for every small activity trigger that gets added to the function since the goal is to verify the final result.

So questions are:

1. Is this even possible?
2. Can I get the Result in setup and return it as an input in another activity trigger setup?

Current unfinished test method:

```csharp
[Fact]
public async Task TestOrchestrator()
{
    // Setup
    var fileContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is some filecontent ");
    var encodedFileContent = Encoding.Latin1.GetString(fileContent);
    const string runId = "changeme";

    var loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger>();
    var clientMock = new Mock<IDurableOrchestrationContext>();

    clientMock
        .Setup(context => context.CallActivityAsync<byte[]>(nameof(GetBlobContentAsByteArray), runId))
        .ReturnsAsync(fileContent);

    // I want EncodeToISO88591 to do it's thing instead of me having to return a fake value.
    // clientMock
    //     .Setup(context => context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(EncodeToISO88591), new DataObject<byte[]>(fileContent)))
    //     .ReturnsAsync(encodedFileContent);

    // I want this to consume the value of EncodeToISO88591, not a fake one.
    clientMock
        .Setup(context => context.CallActivityAsync<bool>(nameof(UploadToSftp), encodedFileContent))
        .ReturnsAsync(true);

    //Act

    await RunOrchestrator(clientMock.Object, loggerMock.Object);

}
```

OrchestratorFunction:

```csharp
public record DataObject<T>(T Data);

const string OrchestratorFunctionName = nameof(RunOrchestrator);
const string EncodeFunctionName = nameof(EncodeToISO88591);
const string GetBlobContentFunctionName = nameof(GetBlobContentAsByteArray);
const string UploadToSftpFunctionName = nameof(UploadToSftp);


[FunctionName(OrchestratorFunctionName)]
public static async Task RunOrchestrator(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger logger)
{
    if (!context.IsReplaying)
        logger.LogInformation("Starting Orchestration");

    var runId = context.GetInput<string>();

    byte[] blobContent = await context.CallActivityAsync<byte[]>(GetBlobContentFunctionName, runId);
    string encodedContent = await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(EncodeFunctionName, new DataObject<byte[]>(blobContent));
    bool sftpUploadSuccess = await context.CallActivityAsync<bool>(UploadToSftpFunctionName, encodedContent);

    if (!sftpUploadSuccess)
        logger.LogError("Failed to upload to sftp");

    if (!context.IsReplaying)
        logger.LogInformation($"Completed Orchestration of instance {context.InstanceId}");
}
```

Comment: I admit that I'm lazy, but hey, Stack Overflow users give *free* advice, so: It looks as though you've already written `RunOrchestrator` and now you're asking about how to unit test it. Is that correct?

Comment: Kind of @MarkSeemann! I know how to create the tests but unsure how to do partial tests. Like only test the activity triggers that call external services

Comment: Maybe try `.CallBase().ReturnsAsync(encodedFileContent);`

Comment: What do you mean by *partial test?*

Comment: @MoNazemi, that doesn't work since CallBase returns an IReturnResult that you cannot call ReturnAsync on. And only using CallBase results in an exception "System.NotImplementedException : This is a DynamicProxy2 error: ..."

Comment: @MarkSeemann, A partial test/mock is to only mock parts of a class' methods. Like only mock methodA and methodB but don't override/mock methodC.

Comment: One option is to redesign the code so the EncodeToISO88591 function takes the value as a parameter instead of the IDurableActivityContext. Then I could just call that from the testcase and assert the value and maybe pass that along to other functions that gets added. This might however be a problem if I rely on a property from that context in a function.